# getStaticProps never called (Nextjs 13)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple page on which I'd like to call getStaticProps :

```
const TagPage = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <h1>hi</h1>;
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      hi: "hi",
    },
  };
}

export default TagPage;
```

But I only get  `params: { tag: 'quotidien' }, searchParams: {} }` from the console.log
My file is under app/site/tag/[tag]/page.tsx
Can someone explain me why it isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

just read that you can't use getStaticProps in app folder.
Link : https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: The new app dir added better server-side fetching with normal async functions. Check it out here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching